# Get/Set TextBlock XML Text Value within it's tags

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, textblock

I can get and set the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` but i don't know to get the text corresponding the the one inside XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock">This is what i want to get/set</TextBlock>
```

I want to add html special characters/codes that's why the "text" attribute doesn't help, for example:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock">&#160;&#160;Whatever<LineBreak />More Text</TextBlock>
```

Which works perfectly inside TextBlock tags but not when setting the property

```
myTextBlock.Text = "whatever..."
```

which breaks the content and instead shows:

```
&#160;&#160;Whatever<LineBreak />More Text
```

Comment: I think you need to expand on what it is that doesn't work and what you're expecting.

Comment: It's everything there, i want to get/set where it says "This is what i want to get/set", just that, setting the "Text" attribute doesn't work as expected, i don't know what more to explain :/ just how to get/set that.

Comment: Why do you set the attribute if you can set the content, What is the problem?

Comment: Because (as i said) i don't know how to set the content inside the <TextBlock></<TextBlock> tags.. i want to get/set what is inside (again as i already said: <TextBlock>I WANT THIS!</TextBlock>)

Comment: What are you even talking about, you already set the content. Are you talking  about setting it in C# or what?

Comment: @GotyMetal it's still unclear.  What are the weird characters?  What are you doing to get them? What do you expect?

Comment: Title says c# WPF, yes i can PUT what i want in the XML, but once app is launched, from code, HOW to get/set that value? FROM CODE, sorry if i wasn't clear, like:

myTextBlock.somethingHere("&#160;&#160;Whatever<LineBreak />More Text");

Comment: Do you mean `myTextBlock.Text = "whatever..."`? That's what you're looking for? If it is, take a look at @H.B.'s answer - you won't be able to use stuff like `"&#160;"` or `"<LineBreak />"` in a C# literal string - or at least it won't yield expected results.

Comment: Please read the description, that's exactly what i DON'T want, i want the text BETWEEN  the textblock tags NOT the text attribute.

Comment: What the heck, is that edit i made correct or not? What Grx70 said *is exactly what you seem to mean but can't formulate*.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the `Text` attribute sets the `Text` property, the element content corresponds to the `Inlines` collection, which can be mixed content. `Text` is essentially shorthand for a single `Run`.

If you want to set those in code you can do that, but the encoding of Unicode works differently. If you want line breaks as in XAML you can either build the same structure using `Runs` for strings and the `LineBreak` inlines or encode the line-break directly.

In a normal C# string you can use `\uXXXX` syntax. For  it would be `"\uD83D\uDCA4"`.

If you have complex text with styling you will need to read the `Inlines` to get all the information from the `TextBlock`.

Comment: That was what i was searching for! Thanks! =D